# How to render an array in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

In my Rails application, I have a class `Bar` and a controller  `FooController`.

```
class Bar
   attr_accessor :id
end

class FooController < ApplicationController
   def index
      @rows = {}
      bar = Bar.new
      bar.id = 1
      @rows[0] = bar

      render "index"
   end
end
```

In the view, I would like to render like this

```
<table>
<% @rows.each do |bar| %>
  <tr>
    <td><%= bar.id %></td>
  </tr>
<% end %>  
</table>
```

But it will throws error

```
undefined method `id' for [0, #<Bar:0x00007fc65db33320 @id=1>]:Array
```

If I render like this:

```
<%= @rows %>
```

the raw data of the array `@rows` will be rendered as:

```
{0=>#<Bar:0x00007fc65db33320 @id="1">}
```

How do I render the elements one by one?

Comment: With the code you have shown, it should not be throwinng that undefined method error. Are you sure it's coming from that line?

Comment: Your example and its output don't match. According to your code (`@rows[0] = bar`), the "raw data" should have a key of `0`, not `1`. Please provide a valid example and also include the whole error message, including the error's line number.

Comment: @Stefan: Yes you are right. Sorry again. I have just corrected it in the question.

Comment: @kbisang it makes much more sense now, thanks for taking the time to edit the question!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that `@rows = {}` doesn't assign an array but a hash. And therefore `@rows[0] = bar` doesn't store `bar` as the first element in the array, but it stores `bar` under the key in the hash.

Just change your controller method to:

```
def index
  @rows = []

  bar = Bar.new
  bar.id = 1

  @rows << bar

  render "index"
end
```

Comment: Doesn't explain the _"undefined method 'each' for nil:NilClass"_ error – hash does respond to `each`.

Comment: Great, that helps! Thanks Spickermann for your correct answer.

Comment: the problem was that I filled the array *@rows* like this *@rows[0] = bar* instead of *@rows << bar*

Comment: @kbisang I don't see how that could result in the given error message.

Comment: and of course the array should be defined as `@rows = []` instead of `@rows = {}` as spickermann answered.

Comment: @Stefan: Do you reproduce it in your development environment?

Comment: @kbisang what do you mean? If i have `@rows = {}` and `@rows[0] = 'foo'`, then `@rows.each { ... }` doesn't give an error. Hashes can be traversed via [`each`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.1/Hash.html#method-i-each) just fine (of course).

Comment: @Stefan: Sorry you are right (of course)! The example above will throw the error `undefined method 'id' for [0, #<Bar:0x00007fc65db33320 @id=1>]:Array` not the "*undefined method 'each' for nil:NilClass*" error. Excuse me. The keys gets traversed correctly but by the traversion of the values it will throw the "*undefined method 'id' *" error.